# Bootstrap component to use?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How should I go about designing the following page using Bootstrap? I want to know what components can be used in this situation.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would look at the bootstrap website here: http://getbootstrap.com specifically the 'CSS' and 'Components' sections.

Looks like you could reproduce that image with their navbar, form-group for the search, and a table for the selectable elements in those columns.